# unabel to creat new project using create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I've just finished installing creat-react-app successfully.But ,when I creat a new project like below command ,error happens ,Could you please give me a recommandation ?

```
npm install -g yarn
yarn global add create-react-app
create-react-app myapp
```

**I get this error**

```
PS C:\Users\ZAKARIA\Desktop\react> create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\ZAKARIA\Desktop\react\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2fparser: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ZAKARIA\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-25T19_22_40_652Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from C:\Users\ZAKARIA\Desktop\react
Done.
```

** I deleted cache yarn and I got the same error. **

Comment: Works for me. Are you using a vpn? Also what version of create-react-app do you have?

Comment: yes ,I am using vpn,

Comment: version yarn v1.22.15  , I install creat-react-app latest version